# Reviews Count for each user

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sql table filled with user reviews and captures the following for each entry.

first name, last name, invoice number, invoice date, salesperson & Branch ID

I want to display the total number of reviews that each salesperson has gotten. but having a bit of brain block.

It shows there is 58 reviews for each user in the table but in total there is only 58 reviews for all users

This is the query that i have. Any ideas, Recomendations?

```
$query_TotalReviews = "SELECT COUNT(star_rating) AS 'totalcount' FROM customer_reviews WHERE branch_id = '$SFBranch'";
```

This is my first project so very super noob to all this..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it shows there is 58 reviews for each user in the table but in total there is only 58 reviews for all users

Comment: You're missing `GROUP BY salesperson`.

Comment: You should also select the salesperson, otherwise how will you know who the counts are for?